# Questions about the Xbox One deal (free game) going on next week (Sept. 7 - 13)

Tags: xbox-one, forza-motorsport-5

Next week Microsoft is offering a deal where if you buy an Xbox One, you get a new game of your choice for free. You can also get the deal with their various bundles as well. Meaning that if you bought their Madden 15 Xbox One bundle, you would get Madden 15 included, as well as a free game of your choice (most likely Destiny in my case).

The thing is, I can't find any Madden 15 bundles that have a Kinect included (which I want). Similarly, my friend would like to do the deal and get the Forza bundle, but he can't find any Forza bundles that don't have a Kinect (which he doesn't want).

Luckily for us, if we have to we can both take part in the deal and just buy each other's bundles and swap games, but ideally we wouldn't have to do that. I get the Forza bundle because it came out when the Kinect was mandatory when buying an Xbox One, but why would the Madden 15 bundle not have an option for Kinect or no Kinect? Or does it and I've just missed it?

Comment: Unfortunately until the deal actually starts we don't know how it works. You can contact microsoft/xbox directly through their twitter/store page and ask them how it will/does work. I do know that bundles count towards the offer, but bundles are usually as is(they only come with kinect or only come without it... not a choice) Your friend could just get the kinect bundle and you buy it off him... that sounds viable given your situation.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what we'll end up doing. I was more curious than anything. Not sure why this question is getting down voted, and I would also argue it is not off-topic as everything I mentioned has already been released. The sale next week is merely what brought my attention to the fact that these bundles aren't offered with a mix of features (e.g. Kinect and non-Kinect).

Comment: Time related questions are probably off-topic anyway as after the event ends the question/answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to find any similar bundle for Madden 15 with the Kinect. As far as *why* none is included, that's really left up to speculation as this point since Microsoft hasn't released any official statements (from what I can find) about it.

If I were to speculate, I would say it's likely due to the fact that typically game-specific bundles don't have two versions based off the inclusion of the Kinect. Due to the fact that Madden 15 doesn't require Kinect, it makes sense to offer the lower price point for potential buyers.

Do note another thing you could do is both buy your desired console bundle, and then just pay your friend the difference for the Kinect ($100).